# Select points on Scatter Plots in JavaScript Plotly instead of zooming

Tags: plotly.js

Is it possible to overwrite the default behaviour on zoom event? I would like to select points in the region on Scatter Plots in JavaScript Plotly instead of zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set `layout.dragmode = 'select'` to change the default behaviour, see https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-dragmode.